# Phonegap multiple instances

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, multiple-instances

Hi I'm working on a phonegap / jquery mobile  app. It is an audio (media.play) based app. I have the problem of multiple instances with StatusBarNotification plugin. I've tried to force with android:launchMode="singleTop" and it seems to work fine, but in some strange cases a new instance of the app opens, and the first one is working on background with the audio running.

It is quite annoying becouse I can't stop the audio until I get back to the first one. Is there a piece of code that really forces to only one instance?

I've heard about launchMode="singleInstance", but don't know really the difference.. what will be better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It strictly depends on the device, where you run your application. Consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643658/1469208) to see, that on some devices (here: HTC) using `android:launchMode="singleTask"` rather than `android:launchMode="singleTop"` solve the problem.